# Jenkins Build to made unstable on particular stage with specific error

Tags: jenkins, groovy, try-catch, checkmarx

Actually we are trying to make jenkins Build as Unstable on some particular stage if that stage fails with specific word , Let me give you the context , Actually we have a stage for check marx scan and when that stage runs , if check mars scan is failed we have made that stage as failure and come out of the jenkins job and job will end in that stage without proceeding further,  But  again now In the same stage we are getting an another error saying " some sentence here" and then job is failing because of that , But we dont want that to fail , we just want to make that as Unstable and want to skip the next stages.

Basically I want my check marx scan to stage to be unstable if it has that error with above senetnce mentioned , Anything can be done via jenkins file using try ,catch ??

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with `catchError` functionality:

```
script {
  catchError(buildResult: 'UNSTABLE', stageResult: 'UNSTABLE', message: 'Message') {
    sh "<your script here>"
  }
}
```

Additional documentation [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#catcherror-catch-error-and-set-build-result-to-failure)

Comment: Hi  Ymochurad, Thanks your for your Inputs on this.  As  you said the same catch Error can be used If I am writing Groovy command using pipeline syntax for checkmarx scan instead of the shell command that yo have showed above. Actually In-place of sh "<your script here >" , I am writing groovy syntax for checkmarx which I have generated using pipeline Syntax generation , I hope the same Can be doe for that also to Make my stage as Unstable

Comment: Yes, this should be working. If that doesn't please, share a snippet of your groovy code.

Comment: Sure  Yymochurad, Thanks for the details and will let you know If it hasn't worked for me.

Comment: Hi Yymochurad, Actually Irrespective pf the error message that it is giving , the above one makes job as unstable , and Actually My requirement is bit different , And moreover how can i stop that stage there and exit the build ?? Any help on this is highly appreciated .